# Updating an Observable Collection Based on a combobox selection

Tags: wpf, valueconverter

So I have an ObservableCollection of items called "Class1" and
Class1 has a property named "ID".

I use a datagrid from the WPFToolkit and bind to this collection.
Within the datagrid is a combobox column and I bind it's ItemsSource to the ID property of the class.

At this point, all is good and everything populates as it should. What I want to do is modify the ObservableCollection to reflect the value selected in the ComboBox.

I have a ValueConverter bound to the SelectedItemBinding on the ComboBox as follows:

```
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=ID, Converter={StaticResource IDConverter}}
```

What is the best (i.e: WPF approved method) of modifying the collection? When the IDConverter ConvertBack() method is called, I get the appropriate Class1 instance, but I can't access the Observable collection from within the ValueConverter and I also don't have access to the SelectedIndex value from the Datagrid.

I could create a class as a static resource with a pointer to my collection and pass that as a ConverterParameter, but that seems sort of hokey and I'm assuming there must be some slicker way of doing this with databinding.

Comment: So is the problem that when you modify the ID, it is not reflecting in the datagrid? or when you modify the value IN the datagrid, it is not reflecting elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

For the record, a simple solution is to create a local resource with a reference to the collection you wish to modify as a dependency property. You can then pass this as a ConverterParameter and have access to it in the ConvertBack() interface method.

A caveat: You will most likely encounter a DeferRefresh exception when you make changes to the collection and then you lose focus.
An excellent fix is found here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/187b2b8f-d403-4bf3-97ad-7f93b4385cdf